# MediaPlayer Stop

Tags: android, media-player

How stop playing audio when click back button ? or exit application it's keeping playing on background

I made application has 2 activities first Main welcome activity you click on start button show second activity which contain grid view for multiple images when click on an image start play different sound , but when click back button switch to Main activity but sound keep playing !! and if click home also keep playing?
how to stop it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell it to stop in the `onPause()` of the Activity.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (player.isPlaying()) {
        player.stop();
    }
}
```